# How to extract specific numerical values from a inputted string using cin?

Tags: c++, input, cin

```
1U = 1.2A
1U = 2.3B
1U = 3.4C
1U = 4.5D
1U = 5.6E
1U = 6.7F
1U = 7.8G
```

The code above is the input. Is there a way to only extract the numbers from each line? For example, in the first line, the only values I want is 1.2, not the "1U = " or the A after it. I tried using regular cin and getline(), but they detect a string so they cannot receive any input. I also tried using cin.ignore but I believe I used it incorrectly. 
This is what I have so far:

```
 double temp;
 cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
 cin >> temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Will ignore a whole line. But

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '=');
```

will ignore everything up to = so

```
1U = 1.2A
1U = 2.3B
1U = 3.4C
```

would become

```
 1.2A
1U = 2.3B
1U = 3.4C
```

Now you can

```
cin >> temp;
```

Which would read skip whitespace 1.2 into `temp` and stop as soon as it finds something that cannot be a `double`.

```
A
1U = 2.3B
1U = 3.4C
```

then you loop back around to

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '=');
```

which will leave

```
 2.3B
1U = 3.4C
```

and

```
cin >> temp;
```

grabs 2.8 and then repeat again.

Code for this could look like

```
while (cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '=') &&
       cin >> temp)
{
    // use temp
}
```